# Can fs module of nodejs work in browser with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, fs, ytdl

I have tried to create a video downloader extension with ytdl-core. and I need to fs module to achieve that. I set up browserify and write some usage code of ytdl-core in popup.js. But I doesn't generate any error, but it also doesn't download video.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use FS nodeJS API for the browser.
but you can use other alternatives such: https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS